# No php.ini after installing php5.1 on debian 7.0

Tags: php, configuration, config

Lately i've been struggling with installing zend optimizer on my machine (since i needed that for irrelevant purposes), but i found out that it works best on php 5.1. So i get one from HERE and zend optimizer i had stored from my backup disk. Both tar.gz files. I installed php, so now php -v returns with:

```
PHP 5.1.4 (cgi) (built: Jun 10 2013 13:38:28)

Copyright (c) 1997-2006 The PHP Group

Zend Engine v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2006 Zend Technologies
```

Which indicates that it works quite well. However, to install zend optimizer, i need to edit `php.ini` file, which is basically nowhere.
I tried looking for it with where is php.ini , got:

```
php: /usr/lib/php /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/lib/php
```

but obviously in none of those i can find any.
then i tried

```
sudo find / -name "php.ini"
```

and got nothing.

I'm running Debian 7 Wheezy, with apache2, mysql 5.1 and php5.1 - any ideas?

```
Linux sklep 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.41-2+deb7u2 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I'll provide any needed information, to help you help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a PHP script with `phpinfo();` in it.

Run it, and it will show you where the `.ini` file is.